# Send value to a "read" in a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Is it possible to send a response to an "interactive menu" in a shell script but directly when calling it ?

For example, the script `test.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2 #Or something else
echo "menu, select 1 for...."
read choice
if [ $choice -eq 1 ]; then
  echo AMAZING
fi
```

How can i call the script `test.sh` and automatically send him `1` as my choice for the next `read`, without changing the code of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the value you want into the script.

```
echo "1" | /path/to/test.sh
```

Comment: Thanks amazing. To add to this info, I was able to send multiple answers to several read with for example with : `echo -e "1\n2" | bash test.sh`. Cool !